Getting "Task-isolated value of type '() async -> ()' passed as a strongly transferred parameter" in Swift 6
In my Swift 5 project I have this extension to pass an async function to Publisher.map:
import Combine

public extension Publisher {
    func asyncMap<T>(
        _ asyncFunc: @escaping (Output) async -> T
    ) -> Publishers.FlatMap<Future<T, Never>, Self> {
        flatMap { value in
            Future { promise in
                Task {
                    let result = await asyncFunc(value)
                    promise(.success(result))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

However, I cannot compile this in Xcode 16.1 beta using Swift 6, getting:

"Task-isolated value of type '() async -> ()' passed as a strongly transferred parameter; later accesses could race".

Is it possible to migrate this extension to Swift 6 somehow? Already tried to add Sendable and @Sendable everywhere.

(See @Rob's answer for an improved version of this that handles cancellation.)

If asyncMap is required to run on @MainActor, and T is Sendable, then it's straightforward and will just work:
public extension Publisher {
    @MainActor func asyncMap<T: Sendable>(
        _ asyncFunc: @escaping (Output) async -> T
    ) -> Publishers.FlatMap<Future<T, Never>, Self> {
        return flatMap { value in
            Future { promise in
                Task {
                    let result = await asyncFunc(value)
                    promise(.success(result))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

If it is not...I don't believe this is possible without using the universal escape hatch (I'll show it in a moment). The problem is that Future does not mark its promise parameter is @Sendable or sending or anything. It doesn't promise not to hold onto it and run it at some random point itself, and maybe it has side-effects which could cause a race. It doesn't do that, but it's not promised. And I don't think there's any way to really fix that without Apple updating Combine (which they seem to have mostly abandoned a this point).
There is always the universal escape hatch: @unchecked Sendable, and coupled with marking just about every other thing @Sendable will make this work:
struct UncheckedSendable<T>: @unchecked Sendable {
    let unwrap: T
    init(_ value: T) { unwrap = value}
}

public extension Publisher where Output: Sendable {
    func asyncMap<T: Sendable>(
        _ asyncFunc: @escaping @Sendable (Output) async -> T
    ) -> Publishers.FlatMap<Future<T, Never>, Self> {
        flatMap { value in
            Future { promise in
                let promise = UncheckedSendable(promise)
                Task {
                    let result = await asyncFunc(value)
                    promise.unwrap(.success(result))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I'm sorry.
Given what we know of Future, I believe this is actually safe. Lots of things Swift 6 calls unsafe are in fact unsafe, and we just kind of ignore it because "that won't happen" (narrator: sometimes it happens). But I believe we do know that this is safe. Apple just hasn't updated Combine to mark it.

Or.... we could also reimplement Future:
@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public final class SendingFuture<Output, Failure: Error>: Publisher, Sendable {
    public typealias Promise = @Sendable (Result<Output, Failure>) -> Void

    private let attemptToFulfill: @Sendable (@escaping Promise) -> Void

    public init(_ attemptToFulfill: @Sendable @escaping (@escaping Promise) -> Void) {
        self.attemptToFulfill = attemptToFulfill
    }

    public func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S: Subscriber, Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input, S: Sendable {
        let subscription = SendingSubscription(subscriber: subscriber, attemptToFulfill: attemptToFulfill)
        subscriber.receive(subscription: subscription)
    }

    private final class SendingSubscription<S: Subscriber>: Subscription
    where S.Input == Output, S.Failure == Failure, S: Sendable {
        private var subscriber: S?

        init(subscriber: S, attemptToFulfill: @escaping (@escaping Promise) -> Void) {
            self.subscriber = subscriber
            attemptToFulfill { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let output):
                    _ = subscriber.receive(output)
                    subscriber.receive(completion: .finished)
                case .failure(let failure):
                    subscriber.receive(completion: .failure(failure))
                }
            }
        }

        func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) {}

        func cancel() {
            subscriber = nil
        }
    }
}

And then your original code will work, changing Future to SendingFuture.

Whoa, talk about going above and beyond!

I think Rob Napier’s answer is very good (+1).
But I might advise caution with unstructured concurrency (i.e., the use of Task{…}). If you create unstructured concurrency, you bear responsibility for handling cancelation. If you wrap a Task {…} in a standard Future there is no (easy) way to cancel tasks that are underway when the Future is canceled.
If you are going to try to wrap async-await code in a Future, I might suggest that you will want to create a custom AsyncAwaitFuture that will also cancel the associated task if the future is canceled. And then, once you have that, you do not need to implement an asyncMap method, at all, but you should be able to use all of the standard Publisher methods.
So, perhaps:
/// AsyncAwaitFuture

@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public final class AsyncAwaitFuture<Output, Failure: Error>: Publisher, Sendable {
    public typealias Promise = @Sendable (Result<Output, Failure>) -> Void

    private let work: @Sendable (@escaping Promise) async -> Void

    public init(_ work: @Sendable @escaping (@escaping Promise) async -> Void) {
        self.work = work
    }

    public func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S: Subscriber, Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input, S: Sendable {
        let subscription = AsyncAwaitSubscription(subscriber: subscriber, work: work)
        subscriber.receive(subscription: subscription)
    }
}

/// AsyncAwaitFuture.AsyncAwaitSubscription

private extension AsyncAwaitFuture {
    final class AsyncAwaitSubscription<S: Subscriber>: Subscription where S.Input == Output, S.Failure == Failure, S: Sendable {
        private var subscriber: S?
        private let task: Task<Void, Error>

        init(subscriber: S, work: @Sendable @escaping (@escaping Promise) async -> Void) {
            self.subscriber = subscriber
            task = Task {
                await work { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let output):
                        _ = subscriber.receive(output)
                        subscriber.receive(completion: .finished)
                    case .failure(let failure):
                        subscriber.receive(completion: .failure(failure))
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) { }

        func cancel() {
            subscriber = nil
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
}

Then you can do things like:
var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

func singleAsyncFuture(index: Int) -> AsyncAwaitFuture<Int, Error> {
    AsyncAwaitFuture { promise in
        do {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(5))
            promise(.success(42))
        } catch {
            promise(.failure(error))
        }
    }
} 

// Below, I show an Instruments timeline, which was generated by adding
// this sort of instrumentation (e.g., `OSSignposter`):
//
// func singleAsyncFuture(index: Int) -> AsyncAwaitFuture<Int, Error> {
//     AsyncAwaitFuture { promise in
//         let state = poi.beginInterval(#function, id: poi.makeSignpostID(), "\(index)")
//         defer { poi.endInterval(#function, state) }
//         
//         do {
//             try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(5))
//             promise(.success(42))
//         } catch {
//             poi.emitEvent(#function, "error: \(error)")
//             promise(.failure(error))
//         }
//     }
// }

func startWork() {
    cancellable = singleAsyncFuture(index: 0)
        .sink { completion in
            switch completion {
            case .failure(let error):
                logger.error("error: \(error)")
            case .finished:
                logger.debug("finished")
            }
        } receiveValue: { value in
            logger.debug("received: \(value)")
        }
}

Note, in singleAsyncFuture, where I wrap the async-await code in this custom future, I explicitly avoid introducing unstructured concurrency; there is no longer any need for a Task {…} here, and we should avoid doing so.
Or, if you wanted to do a series of these (say, ten of them, but not more than three at a time), it might look like:
func singleAsyncFuture(index: Int) -> AsyncAwaitFuture<Int, Error> {…}

func multipleAsyncFutures() -> AnyPublisher<Int, Error> {
    Publishers.Sequence(sequence: (0..<10).map { self.singleAsyncFuture(index: $0) })
        .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(3)) { $0 }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func startWork() {
    cancellable = multipleAsyncFutures()
        .sink { completion in
            switch completion {
            case .failure(let error):
                logger.error("error: \(error)")
            case .finished:
                logger.debug("finished")
            }
        } receiveValue: { value in
            logger.debug("received: \(value)")
        }
}

So, when I profiled this in Instruments, I first let it run to completion, but the second time, I started it but dismissed the view in question before the tasks finished. In this second example, each future automatically canceled its respective Task (at the ⓢ signpost) when the cancellable fell out of scope:


In short, be wary of code that introduces unstructured concurrency (i.e., Task {…} or Task.detached {…}) without explicit cancelation handling logic.
